# What Medium armors do not incur a speed penalty?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, movement, armor

Which **medium** armors *do not* incur the speed penalty?

My concern is that the NPC Codex lists NPCs wearing breastplate with no armor penalty as opposed to those wearing other armors. (See the [CR 4 Cautious Archer](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/npcCodex/core/fighter.html#cautious-archer) and [CR 5 Adventuring Blacksmith](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/npcCodex/core/fighter.html#adventuring-blacksmith) for two examples of the discrepancy.)

Also, in the listing on the initial equipment page, breastplate reads as 20 ft as opposed to 30ft (no hindrance). I've read a few forums and it seems that everyone suggests wearing breastplate medium armor (to avoid the penalty, yet it still is listed as incurring the penalty?).

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## A traditional [fighter](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/fighter/) at level 3 gets [armor training](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/fighter/#TOC-Armor-Training-Ex-)

While it appears the speed of the *NPC Codex*'s [superstitious mercenary](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/npcCodex/core/fighter.html)—a level 1 fighter—is, in fact, incorrect, any fighter of level 3 or higher that hasn't traded it away *via* an archetype gains the extraordinary ability [armor training](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/fighter/#TOC-Armor-Training-Ex-) that, in addition to other benefits, allows a fighter to "move at his normal speed while wearing medium armor," like a breastplate.

This, at least, explains the cautious archer's speed 30 even though the creature wears a breastplate.

#### Medium armor typically applies a speed penalty

One of the defining characteristics of medium armor is its speed penalty: "Medium or heavy armor slows the wearer down," says [Armor and Shields](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/armor/) on Speed. While exceptions exist for some specific or obscure medium armors—armors that are made of [mithral](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/special-materials/#TOC-Mithral), for example, "are one category lighter than normal for purposes of movement and other limitations"—, the fighters from the *NPC Codex* would say if they were using such armors.